# How to load a form with options from a queryset in Django

Tags: django, forms, radio-button

I am trying to load a form with user payment options, so this is needing a query set from the users profile.

I have tried initializing the form (below code) with user being required. The issue is if I make self.options when I am initializing. I have also tried creating the choice_field

```
class ListPaymentOptionsForm(forms.Form):

    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=options)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.options = list(UserPaymentOption.objects
                                               .values_list('last_four', 'last_four')
                                               .filter(user=user, active=True))
        super(ListPaymentOptionsForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

The above code gives this error:
choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=options)
NameError: name 'options' is not defined

Then I have tried adding the options on the view instead like this

```
form = ListPaymentOptionsForm(user=request.user)
form.fields['choice_field'].choices = list(UserPaymentOption.objects
                                               .values_list('id', 'last_four')
                                               .filter(user=request.user, active=True))
```

This causes an error with the form being used on post, it seems like because it is trying to validate the value provided is a choice but in the actual form the choice is not set. The reason I believe this is the problem is this is what the form returns as

```
form=ListPaymentOptionsForm(request.POST)
print(form)
```

This returns: Choice field:

Select a valid choice. 54 is not one of the available choices.

Any input on this would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there!

Try doing the `fields['choice_field'].choices` in the constructor.

```
class ListPaymentOptionsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # assuming python 3 constructor
    self.options = list(UserPaymentOption.objects.values_list('last_four', 'last_four').filter(user=user, active=True))
    self.fields['choice_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=self.options)
```

Maybe consider having a look at `ModelChoiceField` instead however, that way you can specify a queryset instead of having to worry about creating a `list`:

```
class ListPaymentOptionsForm(forms.Form):
        choice_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=UserPaymentOption.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice_field'].queryset = UserPaymentOption.objects.filter(user=user, active=True)
```

EDIT based on comments we can use the `kwargs` to pass the user which may be better:

```
class ListPaymentOptionsForm(forms.Form):
        choice_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=UserPaymentOption.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user') # this must be done before super()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice_field'].queryset = UserPaymentOption.objects.filter(user=user, active=True)
```

Then instantiate the form to handle POST data:
`form = ListPaymentOptionsForm(request.POST, user=user)`

Comment: Thank you! I really liked the ModelChoiceField option you showed. They both options load the radio button with the queryset, though when I try and post I currently just have `form = ListPaymentOptionsForm(request.POST)` and am getting this error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: @BrentLageson we're passing a `User` instance into the form's constructor, so it'll need to be passed in when you instantiate the form with POST data. Try:
`form = ListPaymentOptionsForm(user, request.POST)`

Comment: I had a similar thought but when I passed the user it said that two instances of the user were given. Which is strange because when I create the Form when its not a post I used `form = ListPaymentOptionsForm(request.user)` and that works as expected. (Again I really appreciate the feedback)

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer with a few changes that should help

Comment: That did it! Thank you again, I tried up voting you but apparently my reputation is still to low.